# HTML-Newsletter: Image adjust

Tags: html, outlook, newsletter

I have made an HTML-Newsletter Template. I have one Bug. How can i adjust images in table layouts? I have tried to to use margin but that wont work on Outlook 2010.

Here ist the Code-Snipet from the image: `

```
<table id="logo" cellpadding="20" cellspacing="0" width="620" align="center">
        <td width="161" height="24" align="left" valign="top">
            <a title="www.xxx.xxx besuchen" href="http://www.xxx.xxx/" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.xxx.xxx/images/header/logo_sub.gif" border="0" alt="www.xxx.xxx besuchen" style="margin-left:-13px !important;"/></a>
        </td>
    </table>`
```

Comment: To be honest your question doesnt give much info about what you want to achieve. My first advice would be not to use negative margins but that surely doesnt solve the problem at hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding columns and rows to the table.  Stick the image in one of the middle columns and apply widths and heights to the surrounding columns to get the image into place.